# c# LINQ Take for internal query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have smth like this

```
DbContext.Level1.GroupBy(level1=> level1.field1, (field1, list1)=>
 new Level1{ 
    field1 = field1,
    level2List = list1.GroupBy (level2 = > level2.field2, (field2, list2) =>
       new Level2 {
          field2 = field2}
   ).Take(takeValue)
 }
).ToList()
```

takeValue could be 10, 20, 30. But sometimes I need to select all possible items. Is it possible somehow to allow Take to get all records?

Comment: Have you tried just using `int.MaxValue` as `takeValue`? Assuming this is all via SQL, you should check what the execution plan looks like in that case.

Comment: Just add `Take` conditionally.

Comment: Gert Arnold >> how? It is an internal query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most readable solution would be inserting `Int32.MaxValue` into `takeValue`. If it exceeds the amount of actual values it'll retrieve the entire collection.